Nestjs app for TCP calls using net or tls modules
I'm working on NestJS application to manage requests arriving via TCP/IP protocol. These requests, received from devices, are in plain string format and follow a position-based structure. I intend to use TLS/NET modules for this purpose. Could you provide guidance on how to implement this? Are there any sample applications available?
Eg, message: ILA00477...
Request is sent to ip:port ie, localhost:7890
